# How to locate unhandled reject that rejected without an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Say I have some codes as below:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log(reason, promise)
})

Promise.reject()
```

`Promise.reject` called without any param, and the `unhandledRejection` handler output something like `undefined Promise { <rejected> undefined }`. There wasn't any information to locate the real promise. **So how can I get the context about the rejected promise in this case?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if the promise has an error or not.

Rejected promises are generally **different from exceptions**. They are asynchronous. And they are just objects.

### Synchronous error handling

You **can** locate where an exception was thrown:

```js
if(true){
  throw undefined //Definitely here
}
```

However, it becomes more complicated if you have functions:

```js
function throwUndefined(){
  throw undefined //Here?
}

function maybeThrow(throwException){
  if(throwException){
    throwUndefined() //Or here?
  }
}

maybeThrow(true) //Or here?
```

Actually, both three places. That's where the error's stack comes in.

It represents the call stack at the time when the exception occurs. In the above example, it would be something like:

```js
throwUndefined (line 2) 
maybeThrow (line 7)
main (line 11)
```

### But promises are different

That stack-stuff can be really helpful for synchronous code, but... asynchrony goes beyond the stack!

When the main script finishes and pops out of the stack, the code doesn't stop: asynchrony begins just there.

### One step beyond the stack

The event loop turns on and starts handling "magical" things, like promises and timeouts.

And now, where is the promise at the *end* of the code?

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve) => { //Here?
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()
    b = a //Or here?
  }, 100)
})
a.then(() => { //Here?
  console.log(b) //Here?
})
let b //Or maybe here?
```

Both of these places!

However, this can **not** be represented by a linear structure (like a stack), since some parts change over time.

If a promise gets rejected asynchronously, it doesn't stop the execution of code. Handlers can be attached later:

```js
const a = Promise.reject() //If the code would terminate here, you couldn't add the catch listener
a.catch(console.error)
```

So the warning is emitted only *after* the stack caused the promise rejection has gone, and other changes might have occurred since then.

Consider the following:

```js
let a = Promise.reject()
a = undefined

//Warning: `a` was rejected! But was it? Well, no... `a` is just `undefined`
```

Or a more realistic example:

```js
const array = [Promise.resolve(), Promise.resolve(), Promise.reject(), Promise.resolve(), Promise.resolve(), Promise.resolve(), Promise.resolve(), Promise.resolve()]
for(const promise of array){
  const x = promise.then() //Forward data to `x`
}

//Warning: `x` was rejected! Exactly which  `x` of the 8?
```

### That's OK, but please answer my question!

> How to find the promise?

It's simple: you've got a reference to it! What else do you need?

If you compare the reference in the `promise` argument of the promises you've used, you can find which one got rejected, and from there it isn't hard to figure out where has it happened.

And a tip at the end: handle all promises (or promise chains), even the ones you don't expect to reject.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and tip, looks like there is no easy way that I can log the stack in `unhandledRejection` event in this case.